# jQuery.ajax not working in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Something in my script is breaking IE.

I'm looking on a collection of links with a class, and hijacking the URL's.
Clicking a link will animate the height and reveal a message. It also
does an ajax request to mark the message as read.

However, in IE it simply goes to the URL instead of staying on the page and processing the http request.

```
$('.message .subject .subject_link').click(function(e) {

    toggle_message(e)
    return false;

});


function toggle_message(m) {

var link = m.target;
var parent = $(link).parent().parent();
console.log(link.href);
$.ajaxSetup({

    url: link.href,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 63000,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false

});

if($(parent).hasClass('unread')) {

    $(parent).addClass('read').removeClass('unread');

    $.ajax({

        complete: function(r, textStatus) {
            console.log(r.responseText)
        }

    });

}

if($(parent).find('.body_wrapper').hasClass('collapsed')) {
    $(parent).find('.body_wrapper').addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed');
    $(parent).find('.body_wrapper').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
    })
} else {
    $(parent).find('.body_wrapper').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
    $(parent).find('.body_wrapper').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
    }) 
}
```

}

any ideas what's causing this issue?
http://support.cooper.krd-design.net/
tester: 12345 if you want to review the page

Thanks
Rich

Comment: @RabidFire answered exactly this. Too bad it was deleted!

Answer (score 0):

Adding

> `e.preventDefault();`

before toggle_message in the first function should work, although return false should as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to IE right now but I think you could try preventing the default click event to fire in your click()-function like so:

```
$('.message .subject .subject_link').click(function(e) {
    toggle_message(e)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

More on .preventDefault() here: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I'll add that as well, just to also prevent in case something gets by.